# Dynamic UITextView as the IOS native SMS-app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I am now trying to develop a chat function like the native one in the iPhone SMS-app. I have followed this guide: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView how to create a TextView that scale's height depending on the amount of text in it.

Ofcourse I want to integrate this with my existing UIViewController built in storyboard (which is a tableView) instead of customizing a new one by code like being done in this tutorial: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView/blob/master/example/Classes/GrowingTextViewExampleViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView {
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:219.0f/255.0f green:226.0f/255.0f blue:237.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
.......................................... etc

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
...........................................etc
}
```

Now, if I wanna replace self.view = [[UIView alloc] code above to be self.view = my viewController from storyboard what shall I type instead? I tried to remove the code instead:

```
//self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

But I am getting bad access error when trying to add subview code [self.view addSubview:containerView]; to the UIViewController in storyboard since self.view should refer to the storyboard if not being set to something else? It worked when it was set to the customized UIView code:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:219.0f/255.0f green:226.0f/255.0f blue:237.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
```

So...To sum this up, how do I add the subView (containerView) to my existent UIViewController in storyBoard ? Here is also a pic of my bad access error: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21acqvb&s=6